# Detect NavigationDrawer state on Fragment

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have a navigation drawer in my BaseActivity. Now I want to detect the NavigationDrawer state(Opened or Closed) in a separate fragment. I tried in Fragment life cycle methods, but no method is triggered when NavaigationDrawer is opened or closed. Any one Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this line of code in your fragment that you want to check if the drawer is closed or not:

```
DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
ListView mDrawerList = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        if (!mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)){

            System.out.println("The Drawer is closed!");

        }
```

Basically you are calling the layout from the activity that is hosting that fragment.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement `DrawerListener` in baseactivity,

```
BaseActivity implements DrawerListener
```

Now you have to assign

```
yourNavigationDrawerObject.setDrawerListener(this);//please put your object behalf of yourNavigationDrawerObject
```

call when navigation drawer close.

```
@Override
public void onDrawerClosed(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

call when navigation drawer open

```
@Override
public void onDrawerOpened(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your navigationdraweractivity make drawer layout as public

```
public DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
```

In your Fragment

```
NavigationsDrawerActivity _activity =(NavigationsDrawerActivity)this.Activity;
```

then add your events

```
this._activity.drawerLayout.DrawerOpened += drawerLayout_DrawerOpened;
this._activity.drawerLayout.DrawerClosed += drawerLayout_DrawerClosed;
```